# how to mock response.headers('location') in jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

In Angular controller, I have some codes like :

```
$http.save('api/purchases').$promise.then(function(response) {
  var location = response.headers('location'); // to retrieve the location in response header
})
```

in jasmine's unit test,

```
it('..', function(){
  $httpBackend.expectPost('api/purchase').respond(201, {}, {location: 'xxx'});
  // when run the test, it reports an error with 'undefined is not a constructor' (evaluting response.headers('location'))
})
```

How can i test the response.headers('location')?

Answer (score 3):

The [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#expect) seem to indicate that respond needs `statusText` when given `headers` (as in it is not optional and is required when passing in `headers`)

> function([status,] data[, headers, statusText])

You should be able to pass some text for a 201 like so

```
$httpBackend.expectPost('api/purchase').respond(201, {}, {location: 'xxx'}, 'Created');
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not the reason

Answer (score 0):

use transformResponse in $resource action

```
var resource = $resource('api/purchase', {}, {
  get: {
    method: 'GET',
    transformResponse: function(data, headers) {
      var response = {};
      response.data = data;
      response.headers = headers();
      return response;
    }
  }
}
```

to retrieve 'location':

```
resource.get().$promise.then(function(response){
  var location = response.headers.location; // 'headers' has been put into response object above
})
```

then test can run normally.